# ionic android build failing with exception

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, ionic-framework

Trying to build my first app using ionic. 
I have added phonegap-plugin-push may be something went amiss here and unable to figure it out. Tried updating the android SDK, installing and reinstalling. Project was initiated only with ionic start appName

I did not mention any bundle identifier while initiating the project. I just did ionic platform add android to add android to the project.

Pasting the log below while running ionic build android.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
> Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+.
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/maven-metadata.xml
     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/
     file:/Users/Yashwanth/NVPACK/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/maven-metadata.xml
     file:/Users/Yashwanth/NVPACK/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/
 Required by:
     :android:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.125 secs

    /Users/Yashwanth/appName/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                ^
Error code 1 for command: /Users/Yashwanth/appName/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/Yashwanth/appName/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/Yashwanth/appName/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /Users/Yashwanth/appName/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:817:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
```

The issue seems to be something related to configuring push. Please help me with a solution.

Comment: You can try installing recent version of *Android Support Repository*, *Android Support Library*, *Google Play Services*, and *Google Repository* in the Android SDK Manager.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the Google Repository on the Android SDK manager fixed it.